# PHP MySQL table results order by date

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have been thinking and searching the whole day about this problem. I have a query:

```
<tr>
        <th>
            <a href="?orderBy=name">Asset name</a>
        </th>
        <th>
            <a href="?orderBy=classification">Classification</a>
        </th>   
        <th>
            <a href="?orderBy=tag">Tag</a>
        </th>
        <th>
            <a href="?orderBy=department">Department</a>
        </th>   
        <th>
            <a href="?orderBy=nextreview">Next review date</a>
        </th>   
        <th>
            <a href="?orderBy=responsible">Responsible</a>
        </th>   
        <th>Update</th>
        </tr>';


    $sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM `assets`
    ORDER BY id";

    if (isset($_GET['orderBy'])) {
        $orderby = $_GET['orderBy'];
     if ($orderby == 'name')
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `assets`ORDER BY Asset_name";
        }
        elseif ($orderby == 'classification')
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `assets`ORDER BY Classification";
        }
        elseif ($orderby == 'tag')
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `assets`ORDER BY Tag";
        }
        elseif($orderby == 'department')
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `assets`ORDER BY Department";
        }
        elseif($orderby == 'Next review date')
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `assets` ORDER BY Review_date asc";
        }
        elseif($orderby == 'responsible')
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `assets`ORDER BY Responsible";
        }
}
```

I have a PHP table that displays the result, the query above works in phpmyadmin, I have tried it several times. However, in PHP, it is not working: it sorts the result seemingly randomly if I click on the header. The date format is `YYYY-MM-DD` and in phpmyadmin it is date. I have tried creating custom fields, or just changing the sql code to DATE(Review_date), but all these work in phpmyadmin but not in PHP code.

Can you please help me? Thanks!

```
if (!($result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql)))
    { die("Could not show the required data" . mysqli_error($conn));}
    elseif (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        while($result2=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$result2["Asset_name"].'</td>
        <td>'.$result2["Classification"].'</td>
        <td>'.$result2["Tag"].'</td>
        <td>'.$result2["Department"].'</td>
        <td>'.$result2["Review_date"].'</td>
        <td>'.$result2["Responsible"].'</td>
       </tr>';
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code of where you execute the query and where you display the results / loop over them.

Comment: It would help if you showed how you loop through the data in php

Comment: try with column field datetime instead of date.

Comment: I have edited with the loop

Comment: what output you get & what u want ?

Comment: I just want the dates to be ordered by review date, which works in phpmyadmin but not in php

Comment: Key phrase: “it sorts the result ... if I click the header.”  The code you’re showing is irrelevant; what is causing sorting when you click a header?  JavaScript? Redrawing the page from a form submission?  An html table doesn’t change unless you intentionally redraw it somehow.

Comment: sorry, you are right, I have updated my code, basically I create links and if a user clicks on the headers, then the sorting should be done

Comment: Where do you collect the ?orderBy parameter on the server side when it sends that back after the click on the header? You haven't shown us how you read that, or how you build the SQL query

Comment: I collect the orderBy parameter only in that php file, it is just an indication which sql code should be run (originally the table is shown ordered by id value)

Comment: ok. So you're saying that when you click on any of those headers, it sorts randomly? Or only the Review_Date one is a problem? It isn't quite clear in your question.

Comment: normally, when I click on one of those headers, it sorts the results of that column ascending order (A-->z). The only place it does not work is the review date. It works in phpmyadmin (order by Review_date asc) but here it does not, it just sorts the date values randomly

Comment: what is the data type of your `Review_date` column in the database? Is it `datetime`? or `varchar`? Although to be honest it's MySQL which does the sorting, so I can't see how the result could possibly be any different whether you use phpMyAdmin or your own PHP script

Comment: it is date, not varchar, I have checked that 3 times as well, that is why I dont know what casues my problem

Comment: Hang on...did you actually debug your PHP? Did you ever verify that it was actually running the SQL you expected it to? Or that the code took the path through the `if` statements you expected it to? That's basic debugging work in a situation like this, to verify your assumptions. I ask this because I took a closer look at the fine details of the code: Compare `href="?orderBy=nextreview"` and `elseif($orderby == 'Next review date')` ...can you spot the difference?

Comment: It took me, who can't run the code, some time to stare at it and eventually notice that, but 2 minutes of debugging to log variables and progress would have made it much easier to see, because you'd have realised the `if` statement wasn't working. The sorting isn't "random", it's just not the sorting you expected.

Comment: Yes, i know what you meant but the if is indented and it works. The $orderby is this if (isset($_GET['orderBy'])) {$orderby = $_GET['orderBy']; and the queries do work (they are sorted right) if I click on e.g. Tag column, it sorts them in ascending order

Comment: That specific If for the review date won't work because you're testing for the wrong value. The string you pass in doesn't match the one you're testing for. That was my point. I don't think you have debugged that or else you'd have noticed it wasn't running the right query

Comment: well, I look like an idiot now and i can feel it as well. Yeah, that was my problem. On the other hand, I have learnt a lot about SQL dates which might be good in the future. Thank you very much for your help!